# Website - how to make an info button for images

Tags: html, image, web, minecraft

I was wondering how you on a website make an info button for images. Like after you click the info button, there is a box beside the mouse telling you what image your mouse is hovering over. This would be for this website: `http://108.171.192.123:8123/` . I want (on the click of a button) for it to tell you what block is what.

Note: 
- the several images can't be made into a bit map
- any code snippets that might help are useful
- any website language I will accept (e.g. I can learn it if I need to).
- huge thanks to those who answer.
- the website is a map of my minecraft server (it will be blank ATM tho)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic MouseOver effects are achived by using JavaScript. I would recommend to learn [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), a widley used JavaScript library, which allows to animate your static html.